# Avoid duplicates in bash history

Tags: bash

Is there a way that I can remove repeated commands from bash history?

For example: I run the `mv` command once, then I run the `ls` command **n** times.

I have to press the up arrow **n** times to get the `mv` command again.

How can I keep just one `ls` command instead of **n**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting the following environment variable:

```
HISTCONTROL="ignoredups"
```

Will prevent duplicate commands from being logged.